# Git: keep a directory different in local and remote repository?

Tags: git, directory, repository, local, gitignore

I want to make a directory different in my local and remote repository. If I add the directory to .gitignore, then the directory in remote repository will disappear when I push.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the directory to `.git/info/exclude` file? It holds local exclusions and should not affect anything on the remote side. (See http://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files.)

I think the `.gitignore` way is also correct unless you push your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: I've tried, but it will remove my directory when push because it think this directory is not needed

Comment: I think your problem is rather connected with committing than pushing. Make sure you had last committed the "remote" version of the directory and you haven't touched it in any ongoing commit you push.